# Could not load type 'Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency' from assembly 'Devart.Data.MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

When I run my code, there is an error as below:

> Could not load type 'Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency' from assembly
>   'Devart.Data.MySql, Version=8.10.1086.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701'.

Which part would cause this problem?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you might be using an older version of the assembly that doesn't include that class. A quick search doesn't reveal what versions support that class but that might be an avenue of investigation for you. Did that error occur during development or after deployment? If the latter, is the deployed version of the assembly the same as the one you're developing against?

Comment: By the way, it may not necessarily help in this case but you should still ALWAYS provide the relevant code.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Based on the code provided, the solution is ... 42.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample codes...

```
using Devart.Data.MySql;
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string Query = "Select * from tbltransaction";
    public MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection cn;
    public MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter;
    public DataSet dsdatagrid;
    public DataTable dt;
    public DataGridView datagrid;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Start();
    }

    string connectionString = "User Id=root;Password=123!@#abcD;Host=localhost;Database=kcms1_test;";

    void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand commandDeptEmp = new MySqlCommand("select * from tbltransaction", connection);
            //MySqlCommand commandPict = new MySqlCommand("select * from mysqlnet_pictures", connection);

            MySqlDependency dependency = new MySqlDependency(commandDeptEmp, 1000);
            dependency.AddCommandDependency(commandDeptEmp);
            //dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
            MySqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
            MySqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
            OpenLocalDBConnection();
            View_Data();
            DataGridView_tbltransaction.DataSource = datagrid.DataSource;
        }
        catch
        {
            Stop();
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }

    void Stop()
    {
        MySqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
    }

    void dependency_OnChange(object sender, MySqlTableChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // process changes
        View_Data();
        DataGridView_tbltransaction.DataSource = datagrid.DataSource;
    }
    void View_Data()
    {
        sqlAdapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(Query, cn);
        dsdatagrid = new DataSet();
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dsdatagrid);
        dt = new DataTable();
        datagrid.DataSource = dsdatagrid.Tables;
    }

    void OpenLocalDBConnection()
    {
        cn.ConnectionString = "server=locahost;userid=root;password=123!@#abcD;database=kcms1_test";
        cn.Open();
    }

}
```